# Another language question regarding tomodachi

Tags: word-choice, expressions, slang, culture

my college product line for next year is currently called Tomodachi.  however because someone owns this word in the USA I was hoping to find something similar.  Americans really like the 'dachi' part so it would be ideal if it had dachi in it.  do people still use mabudachi?  is there something similar?  these mascots (120 of them) are all friends but also rivals.  is there any Japanese word that makes sense? any help would be greatly appreciated. my Nihongo is long gone from my days in Tokyo in 82/83.   [here is what the characters look like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6xs5uuxreyi51k/tomodachi%20show.jpg?dl=0) again.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a dachi-ending word but, how about *nakamatachi*?

Comment: maybe one vowel too long.. tachi ending is fine though.

Comment: 友人たち maybe? yūjintachi

Answer (score 1):

> do people still use mabudachi?

mabudachi is old word. It used about 20 years ago by high school gang. But many Japanese still know that word.

Usage of a phrase 'dachi' has slightly high school gang atmosphere. 
ダチ公(dachi-ko) has same meaning with dachi.

Now (last 3 months) nice animation けものフレンズ had broadcasted widely in Japan. Many anime fan use the word フレンズ(friends) on twitter, so I think フレンズ may good for you.

Comment: in the usa the more 'japanese' the word sounds the more authentic it will be perceived.  so friends wont work.  I need something that ends in dachi or something that sounds Japanese.  its hard but I am trying to find something that is good in japan and in usa..  thanks